# Spring MessageSource basename path problems

Tags: java, spring, utf-8, thymeleaf

I am currently working on a Spring Project and want to link my messages.properties in a `@Bean` to enable UTF-8 Encoding.

This is my project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

And this is the Bean in the `ServletInitializer.java`:

```
@Bean
ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    source.setBasename("messages");
    return source;
}
```

However, when I run this my website dows not show the messages but rather their id's (codes):

`??catalog.title_de??`

What would be the correct way of showing it the path to my messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing much more about your project, I think I can only suggest setting `basename` to `classpath:messages` instead of `messages`.